# ORA-00001: Facing the unique constraint issue in multiple tables due to migrated data

Tags: oracle, ora-00001

As part of migration, we have launched new `RDS 19c database` and deployed applications, which automatically created multiple tables exactly as the existing `12c Database`, we have migrated the data from the old DB.

Now when system is trying to insert the data in tables it throws the `Ora-0001` error, as the migrated data already have same unique key available for that table, this is happening with multiple tables at different times.

how can we skip the system generated unique key to generate higher number then the migrated data?

migrated data have unique key up to 55 million and new database started from 1.

thanks

when any table throw the error, If we insert into any other table it skip some number and resolve the issue for that time, but occurs for different tables and different time.

Comment: How do you generate the unique keys?  My guess is that you need to reset one or more sequences.

Comment: Primary key are auto generated by Oracle, below SQL is used to generate:


PCTFREE 20 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
STORAGE(INITIAL xxxx NEXT xxxx MINEXTENTS xx MAXEXTENTS xxxx
PCTINCREASE x FREELISTS xx FREELIST GROUPS xx
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "Table-space"

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You posted the physical storage clauses of an object.  That has nothing to do with generating key values.  Again, my guess is that you have 1 or more sequence objects that you want to reset.  But that's just a guess.